# Split number into two parts

Tags: java

I'm trying to split number (8bit) (0..255) into two numbers like this:
100 (binary 01100100) into 6(0110) and 4(0100).

In C I do it in such way:

```
short row = value >> 4; //value - uint8_t
short col = (row << 4) ^ value;
```

In Java I do it the other way (because C like code don't work properly):

```
short v1 = (byte)(value >> 4);
short v2 = (byte)((byte)(value << 4) >>> 4);
```

It works for numbers from 0 to 103. But for numbers greater than 103 it doesn't work.

p.s.
Actually problem is here:

```
short v2 = (byte)((byte)(value) >>> 4);
=>104 (1101000). I expected to see something like this: 00001000, but result is 11111000 
=>103 (1100111). Result is 111;
```

Fix.

I fixed it in such way:

```
short value = (byte)255;
short v1 = 0;
short v2 = 0;

for(int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
    v2 = (short) (v2 << 1 | ((value >> i) & 1));
    v1 = (short) (v1 << 1 | (value >> (i + 4) & 1));
}
System.out.println(v1 + " " + v2);
```

But I prefer the C way, it's more simple.

Comment: In Java there's no unsigned numbers.

Comment: Do you mean that I can't split number in such way? Should I use another approach?

Comment: Your fix is very complicated, even your C solution is very complicated for a simple task.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind can you show more simple solution for C?

Comment: @FruitDealer see my and DRoW answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
short row = (value >> 4) & 0x0F;
short col = value & 0x0F;
```

This should also work in C.

& keeps only the bits which are 1 at the same position:

```
11111000   // 104
00001111   // 0x0F == 15
--------
00001000   // 104 & 0x0F == 8
           // because only the fourth bit from right is 1 in both numbers!
```

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned char f = 100;
unsigned char first = f >> 4;
unsigned char second = 0xF & f;
printf("%d %d", first, second);
```

00001111 if you bitwise and with number you will get last 4 bit

Comment: 1) Java does not know unsigned char 2) signed char will give problems with negative numbers

Comment: he said c way,not java... and second one is u can't get two signed number from 8 bit. if u want it u must write ur own struct or method.1bit for sign and 7 bit for value how do u split this number to negative?

Comment: 1) Read the question again, he showed us how he does it in C and then asks how to do it in Java (or more precisely asks why this does not work in Java) 2) The question is tagged java 3) if the bit representation of an signed char is `10010110` then the result values should have: `1001` and `0110`, the sign is just ignored.

Comment: i see now if he wants it java he can use byte then .And if you ignore the value why did u need sign and Read this : [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) short: The short data type is a 16-bit signed two's complement integer. he should use byte not short. so u re wrong too

Comment: It doesn't really matter, byte, short, int all take 32 bit in the VM. But it is important that value is a short/int because of shifting of the sign

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
short v1 = (byte)(value >> 4);
short v2 = (byte)((byte)(value << 4) >>> 4);

if(v2<0){
v2 = (short) -v2;
}
```